# Examples of braided vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples, braid-groups, braidings

The following example of a braided vector space is given in my lecture notes:

> Let $k$ be a field, and $n>1$. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space with ordered basis $(e_1, e_2,..., e_n)$. Let $q \in k$ be invertible. Define $s \in End(V \otimes V)$:
> $$s(e_i \otimes e_j) = \begin{cases} q  \: e_i \otimes e_j & i=j \\
>                        e_j \otimes e_i & i < j \\
>                     e_j \otimes e_i + (q - q^{-1}) e_i \otimes e_j & j< i.\end{cases}$$
> Then $(V, s)$ is a braided vector space.

My questions:

- How do you come up with the above example? Are there examples in a similar vein?
  In my lecture notes it says that this example is a one-parameter deformation of another example, namely $(V, t)$ with the twist map $t: e_i \otimes e_j \mapsto e_j \otimes e_i$. It seems, this exploits the canonical surjective group homomorphism $B_n \rightarrow S_n$. However, I am not exactly sure how it does so.
- I suppose you prove that $(V,s)$ is a braided vector space (i.e. checking Yang-Baxter, and taking determinant of the respective transformation matrix) via induction over $n$. Correct?

Comment: Rather than induction on $n$ I would just suggest doing by cases, depending on the relative values of $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to prove it myself - if I get stuck, I'll come back here.